# Are bodies of Devtas and Gods also made of Panch-Tatva?

Tags: gods, body, devatas

Are bodies of devtas (eg- Indra, Vayu etc)and Gods (Vishnu, Shiva etc) also made of Panch Tatva like that of humans ?

Comment: None of the devas that are brahman are made up of any tatvas.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha But in stories of Purans and Mahabharat, it is very clear that they have bodies. Shiva lives on Kailash, Vishnu sleeps of SheshNaag. Brahma get born from the navel of Vishnu etc.
It is extremely clear that they have human like bodies.

Comment: Please note that puranas are mythical writings from memory. They are often used to inculcate bhakti among the masses and small children. If you want to reach the depts of knowledge, then jnana yog is what you need. The very principles and definitions are made up and written in them. Shrutis from Upanishads (meaning, sitting directly near a teacher) is what you should be reading. Out of shatdarshanas - nyaya darshan and perhaps mimasa darshan covers tattava texts.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Purans, Mahabharat are historical books. Period. Never it was believed the stories written it was "myth".People for thousands of years have been believing in them as history.
In Mahabharat, it is explicitly written that it is history.

Comment: Mahabharata are *itihaas* (real events) that are different from *puranas* (non-real ones) that are mythological or made up stories, the sanskrit translation of the word पुरण literally means *made up* and puran means *ancient*. Src: https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3&dir=au#:~:text=n.-,pUraNa,-makeup They are medium of bhakti only. This is evident from the Upanishads only that use itihaas and Puranas differently. For Gyan you, you must seek into Upanishads, where these things are discussed in details.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Purana has multiple meaning. But throughout the human history no one has ever believed them as "myth". Every guru, Every learned man of hinduism consider them to be real history. It is only recently that people have started to consider them as "myth". Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu for example visited vrindavan and other places and revived placed related to Radha Rani who is a Puranic character.

Comment: Your very concept is wrong. Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is a **bhakti** marga guru. You aren't getting intellectual answers from them that are supposed to be Gyan Marg. Check any dictionary in the world, they translate Puranas to mythological stories only. Are you even in the sense that - elephants, horses, and lions talk in a story and you believe it too? On the other hand, there is a very large range of actual gyan yog, tantra, even greater Ramayana and Mahabharata gitas that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu *explicitly* rejected as deviation from bhakti.

Comment: The difference between Bhakti marga and gyan marga is that bhakti relies on belief of some infinite power called brahman and gyan marga approaches it by intellectual self-inquiry, texts such as Upanishads (that serve as hints, not dictate intellectual arguments). The third part is yoga marga, which is a sub-part of gyan marga where tantra and other gitas of Krishna arise, unfortunately, Chaitanya Mahaprabhu rejected them too. Nevertheless, all paths are powerful, my salutations to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and his beautiful way of bhakti yoga.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha If Puranas are myths. Why not a single scholar of Hinduism consider them to be myth ? Every single scholar of hinduism, siddh purush, people with spiritual power consider Purans to be history. 
Only those people of hinduism consider them to be myth who have no spiritual power neither have any siddhis. Most don't even know sanskrit.
Also for thousands of years people have been considering them to be history. 
It is only recently in past 200-300 years or so some people have started to view Purans as myths.

Comment: This is because the very meaning of the word *puranas* is *a collection of mythical stories*. See the Sanskrit dictionary: https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3&dir=au . I'm not sure about past 200-300 years, but even Upanishads make proper distinctions between *itihaas* and *puranas*, while former being real history (Ramayana, Mahabharata), later is mythical for the groups for the time TV, Newspaper hadn't emerged and people were taught the concept of vedas through mythical stories.

Comment: How do you assume I'm not a Siddha? (I'm not even joking here!)

Comment: **Don't** defame me on useless things: *I remember you were once considering Astavakara Gita to be superior to Bhagwat Gita, when Bhagwat Gita is spoken by god while Astavakra is just a human*. I've actively considered all three Krishna Gitas as Upanishads. I already told you with a dictionary, that *Puranas mean Myth/Ancient* and hence Upanishads separate Itihaas and Puranas in all their verses. Puranas were compiled **thousands of years after** Vedanta (10 C.E. - 1K C.E.). Therefore, no one can point out Mahapuranas back in Vedanta.

Comment: Further, I refuse to engage you on this particular topic, if you keep misquoting me. You are free to disagree with me or defame me particularly don't care if you are hurtful about it. I've presented my points very well and my practices are confined to me and my own spiritual path. Thank You.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Okay I take back my point  if you think I was defaming you and I delete my comment. If you don't mind, which three krisna gitas you were talking about. I only know one Krishna Gita - Bhagwat Gita. Which are the other two ?

Comment: There are three Krishna Gitas from Mahabharata: 1. Anu Gita (The duty, moral, ethics, as an appendix to Bhagavad Gita) 2. Bhagavad Gita (summary of the epistemology of previous 63 Gitas) 3. Uttara Gita (Introductory text on Kundalini Tantra and Advaita). Apart from that, Mahabharata has other Gitas too : Vyadha Gita (A dialogue between an enlightened butcher and a Siddha brahmana). There are Gitas in Ramayana also: Rama Gitas and so on. There are 7 principal gitas: Shiva, Bhagavad, Devi, Surya, Ashtavakra, Vyadha, Uttara), rest all are less common to best of my knowledge.